# Differen in Python list

Tags: python, list

If List A= [1,2]
and List B=[2,4]

I want the difference between A and B which is present in B.

that is, diff between A and B is [1,4]... should be present in B... SO the final output should be C=[4]

Comment: did you try something ?

Comment: You could use sets. `set(B).difference(set(A))`

Answer (score 0):

use **sets()**

```
A = {1,2}
B = {2, 4}

print(B.difference(A)) 
or
print(B - A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the XOR `^` operator in set:

```
lst_A = [1,2]
lst_B = [2,4]

print(list(set(lst_A) ^ set(lst_B)))
```

OUTPUT:

```
[1,4]
```

Comment: From the question: "the final output should be C=[4]". So not the symmetric difference.